# Finding area enclosed by $xy = \sqrt{x!y!}$ on the positive x axis

Tags: integration, area

I want to find the area enclosed by $xy = \sqrt{x!y!}$ on the positive x axis, which is the area shown on the image. How can I do it using integration? And I'm willing to find a closed expression rather than a numerical value (if it's possible)

[image: The area that I'm willing to find]

I don't know where to start, I tried setting up an expression for y, but I couldn't. Can I maybe do it through vector calculus? Or maybe setting up a parametric equation with respect to t? Thank you in advance

Progress: Right now I'm trying to set up a patametric equation, but still working on it

Comment: Do you compute the factorials via Gamma ?

Comment: Do you mean letting the ecuation be $xy = \sqrt{\Gamma(x+1) \Gamma(y+1)}?$

Comment: I mean that usually factorials are defined for naturals.

Comment: In that case yes

Comment: No integrals. I used a graphic method and found about $10.2574$

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Hi Yves ! Any idea ? I am totally stuck with this interesting problem.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: very little. This must be made numerically, and the first idea to mind is to solve for $y$ for each $x$. Other idea is to look at the equation as $(x-1)!/x=y/(y-1)!$, or $f(x)=1/f(y)=t$. Now if you generate values of $t=f(x)$, but also the corresponding inverses, $t'=1/t=1/f(x')$ by some magic (reflection formula ?), you get as many $(x,y)=(x,x')$ as you want.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. I had the same idea but ... Cheers

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I tried to see if I could make use of Green's Theorem in teh plane and write $\text{Area}=-\oint_C y\,dx=\oint_C x\,dy$.  Alas, there was nothing "magical" that I could see to proceed.

Comment: @perch What is the context of this problem?  Where did you encounter it?  With what tools were the prospective problem solver assumed  to be equipped?

Comment: @MarkViola That's the method that I wanted to use. The context of this problem is none, I came out with that equation and I was experimenting

Comment: I would proceed with a numerical integration.